# Weird padding on the VTC privilege notice

Tags: bug, status-review, design, vote-to-close

I pressed the 'Close' button on a question (by the comments). I didn't actually VTC, I just pressed the button.

It seems like there should likely be more padding next to the `Got it` button.

Although I'm not totally sure, I suspect that this is due to the long site name and that it means that the popup box ends up being too small.

Some possible solutions include:

- Simply make the popup box bigger (it isn't user-resizable via the UI)
- Shorten the message to `Thanks for contributing to Programming Language Design and Implementation SE.` (or similar) - I don't know how many people will be familiar with `SE = Stack Exchange` and loosing `We <3 you` would be a bummer

Here's a screenshot of the dialog I'm referring to

[image: Screenshot of popup showing error]

Comment: What device are you on? It didn't look like that for me.

Comment: 13" laptop, full-screen browser (based on Chromium), Windows 10

Comment: Lol the site name is just too long for the popup to handle

Comment: I think this is a symptom of how long our site name is. Perhaps we could ask the devs to abbreviate it in dialogs?

Comment: Abbreviations might cause problems though, as PLDI is used for a conference thing I hear?